# How do you determine the legal index range for an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning Java and walking myself through the exercises hosted online at Towson University and I'm stumped on this exercise.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Overflow2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[]vals = new int[10];

        System.out.println("how many values should be stored in the array? ");
        int count = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            vals[i] = count - i ;
        }

        System.out.println("Which value do you wish to retrieve? ");
        int which = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your value is " + vals[which]);
    }
}
```

For the line

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    vals[i] = count - i ;
}
```

**How does one determine the legal index range?** I assumed that, given

```
int[]vals = new int[10];
```

the index range would be the length of the array - 1, so 9, but this doesn't seem to be correct. The format for the solution is

number -- equality operator -- i -- equality operator -- number

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check to see if it is `0` or more and that it is less that the `length` property

Comment: `0 <= index < array.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assumed that ... the index range would be the length of the array - 1, so 9, but this doesn't seem to be correct.

It is correct. The legal indices are 0 through 9, inclusive. The program will only work if the user enters `10` or less. If they enter something bigger than `10` it will crash with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You're only wrong if one is being pedantic about terminology: to be precise, the *maximum index* is 9. A *range* would have two endpoints. You could describe the range variously as any of these:

- 0-9
- [0, 10)
- [0, 9]
- 0 ≤ i ≤ 9
- 0 ≤ i < 10

Comment: This is where I'm stumped. Maybe it's an error on the part of the university that wrote the exercise, but it will not take 0 through 9. 

Am I correct in assuming that this is 0 <= i =< 9?

Comment: That explains it, thank you. I suppose Towson took the very technical root then.